# How to Restrict Access to Certain Folders under Project on TFS Server

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, devops

I have folder (Solution) on TFS/DevOps, under that solution I have 5 sub projects. I want to restrict access to 3 projects so developers will not be able to download or sync those projects folders in their local Visual Studio.
But they will be able to download and work on 2 projects and then check-in the code.
Is there any way I can restrict the access to those 3 projects (folders) on TFS.

Answer (score 2):

If you use GIT you can not restrict access to a folder. Consider using submodules and restricting access to referenced repositories ([Git Tools - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)).

If you use TFVC you can restrict access to folders: [Control access to Team Foundation Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/control-access-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops)